# CRM 2011 Timezone in OnChange Event

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm in the process of customizing our CRM solution. Due to different timezone, sometimes due dates in Cases or Tasks are not consistent because the time defaults to midnight 12 am. So to different timezone the due date could be one day later or earlier.

In order to fix this we're setting the default time of the due date field (logical name = "followupby" ) to 7 PM. We're creating an OnChange event for the Due date field with Java script function as follow. In "Handler Properties" dialogue to set up the Library and Function name, I check the option to "Pass execution context as first parameter". Therefore in my function below it's receiving the 'context' parameter:

```
setCaseDueDate: function (context) {

    var oField = context.getEventSource().getValue();
    var sTmp = oField;

    var hours =19;
    var minutes = 0;
    var seconds = 0;

    if (typeof (oField) != "undefined" && oField != null) {

        var newTime = new Date(sTmp.getFullYear(), sTmp.getMonth(), sTmp.getDate(), hours, minutes, seconds);
        context.getEventSource().setValue(newTime);
    }        
},
```

However I keep getting an error that says "There was an error with this field's customized event. Error 'setCaseDueDate' is undefined."

Could it be that certain values in my function is undefined or is it probably not getting the 'context' parameter correctly?

Thanks, greatly appreciate your help.

******UPDATE***********************

Nevermind this... I was putting my function with existing collection of Javascript functions and then I decided to put into a separate new webresource and it's working now... weird but works.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code to define a JavaScript function is wrong, try with

```js
function setCaseDueDate(context) {
// rest of the code
}
```

and to change the date, it's not necessary the context, for example:

```js
function setCaseDueDate() {
   var fieldName = "followupby";
   var sTmp = Xrm.Page.getAttribute(fieldName).getValue();
   if (currentDate != null) {
      var newTime = new Date(sTmp.getFullYear(), sTmp.getMonth(), sTmp.getDate(), 19, 0, 0);
      Xrm.Page.getAttribute(fieldName).setValue(newTime);        
   }
}
```